# change slider UI with custom image. windows phone

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, slider, custom-controls

I want to add image for slider control is that possible if yes how can i do?

My current screen is like this.

[image]

And i want to achieve something like this.

Instead of slider default ui i want place my image.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we don't have much details I would recommend you to have a look at this page:
http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/customizing-wp7-slider-in-different-ways

You can find some customization examples there.

I guess you want to put an image here:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ThumbControlTemplate1" TargetType="Thumb">
    <Image Source="path to your img" Height="60" Width="50" />
</ControlTemplate>
```

**upd**

In the article on geekchamp you can see the full control template.

Go to `HorisontalTemplate`

There is an element called `HorisontalTrack`. It is a Rectagle now

```
 <Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalTrack" 
           Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
           Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
           Height="12" 
           IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="0,22,0,50" Opacity="0.2"/>
```

Replace it with `Image`. Also you don't need `HorizontalFill`, so make it transparent.

An use a bubble image for the Thumb. Basically that's it.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion this code will change the slider thumb not slider image  i want to change slider image.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by slider image. Could you provide any example of what are you trying to achieve?